# Keep track of time (when app is closed or in background)

Tags: xcode, swift, nsdate, nstimer

I want to execute a very simple code every day from current date. As simple as this;

```
if new day == true {

Days--

}
```

However, I can't find an answer on how to do this - keep track of day changes even when the app is closed or in background?

1. Track if a new day has begun
2. Execute the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to store the date in NSUserDefaults so that its persistent even if app is closed. And whenever you need to compare get the stored date from NSUserDefault and compare it with current Date. If there is a difference of 1 day it means a new day has begun. Execute your logic + store the new date in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

I have used something similar. I used the approach that when the app is open store the start and end date within Core Data.

every time the app is launched check the current date, and see if it is within the start and end date stored within Core Data. if it is it means its the same day, and if its not it means its another day and execute the code (and update the start and end date within Core Data)